# This website (netu.tv) breaks the inspector if you open it. Is there a way to bypass this and download the "protected" video?

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, drm, web-inspector

Here's an example of their player: https://netu.tv/view_page.php?pid=4

When you open the inspector after playing the video, it

- Destroys the contents of the video embed
- Pauses javascript with an anonymous `debugger;` statement
- Prevents you from opening the right-click menu

**Goal:** Download the video in the embed on the page above.

I refuse to believe that a few dev console tricks are preventing me from getting to the video.

Comment: Dev Tools seem to work normally on the linked page in FireFox ..?

Comment: Try to download the video then.

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow (SO) (and all of Stack Exchange (SE)) *must be* self-contained. The goal of SO/SE is to create a repository of questions and answers which are valuable to *future* visitors. Questions which *require* information from off-site/off-page resources are useless once those resources change or die. Any questions where such a resource is *required* to understand the question should be closed as "needs details of clarity", or other appropriate reason. A link to a website might be beneficial *in addition to information (e.g. code) **in the question itself***.

Answer (score 1):

This sort of obfuscation doesn't really provide any protection, and is a waste of time of the developers that pursue it.  It also tends to lead to side effects that developers don't think of, causing compatibility issues.

It's just an HLS stream, and it's not even using DRM.  Assuming someone doesn't want to deal with the not-too-difficult hassle of working around their "protections" in-browser, it's trivial to use a tool like Fiddler to save a copy of the segments as they're proxied on through.

If this is your site, I'd urge you to not bother with trivial browser hacks, implement industry-standard DRM, and call it a day.  This won't totally stop piracy but it's definitely better than disabling the developer console and right-click.

Comment: It's not my site. Also, to be fair to whoever did make it, it does prevent mildly savvy people from getting at the video without third party tools